# change type from user stories to feature

Tags: rally

I want to move about 100 user stores to features. I use query to get the type, but I don't know how to change it.

query.query_string = "(FormattedID = \"US4332\")"

results = @rally.find(query)

@res = results.first

puts @res["_type"]

Comment: Meaning you want to turn a user story into a Feature?  Or that you want to sub 100 user stories to a (or several) features?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it is not possible to change work item type, and this limitation is not specific to Web Services API, and applies to UI too, with the exception of converting a defect to a story in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you'll be able to get is to create new features as close to copies of the original stories as possible (including moving children, etc).